# Azure devops - update json file - powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have created powershell script to update json file with variables. Json file is located in Azure devops repo, json file name var.json.
I am going to use this solution in azure devops, so I built pipeline and set test variable in variables tab in azure devops:

[image]

In my script I have param and variables blocks, presented below:

```
param(
    [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $FileRes
)
#env variable
$Path = $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY

# Download variables from Json file
$JsonBase = @()
$JsonPath = "$Path\Var.json"
$JsonBase = Get-Content $JsonPath | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json

$JsonBase.FileNames[0].value = $FileRes
```

in my script I use commands: `$JsonBase | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path $JsonPath` to direct output to json file.

Json file structure:

```
{
    "FileNames":  [
                      {
                          "value":  "AAAbbbccc123",
                          "value1":  "www",
                          "value3":  "swd",
                          "value4":  "xvb"
                      }
                  ]
}
```

Pipeline's status at the end is ok, all steps are green, but var.json file is not updated as I wanted. There is still old value --> `"value":  "AAAbbbccc123"`

Comment: What happens if you change it to `"test" | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path $JsonPath`?

Comment: In this situation, script will overwrite json file content, content of json file will be "test".

Comment: Good, so the line that sets the file content works and is being executed. That can only mean one thing, the line that changes the data is not being executed, or does not do what you think it does. When I try with the sample code you provide here, it works. And that means your *real* code is different from your question here.

Comment: Problem is that I tested this code as well, on my laptop lacally, it worked. It doesnt work on azure devops.

Comment: @Tomalak - Did You tested Your code on azure devops or on locally?

Comment: Locally. PowerShell code is PowerShell code. Also, if it properly saves a test value to the file – as we have found out – then the "Azure devops" context is very likely not related to your issue here.

Comment: ok, but still dont know why the same code work on my local laptop and doesnt work on devops.

Comment: You're not showing us how you save the updated `$JsonBase` to file. Are you sure in both environments you have a valid path in variable `$Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` ?

Comment: Do you want to update `var.json` in your git(?) repo? Or just the build directory? The code you posted should update the file that is used in the build itself ie `$Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` If you run `Get-Content $jsonPath` at the end of your build does it output the updated value?

Comment: I ve added powershell task, and in inline section I pasted code: git config --global user.email "agent@no-mail.com"
git config --global user.name "xx"
git add var.json
git commit -m "Json file update"
git push, bit still is something wrong, what should I add to this git commands?  I used option: "Allow scripts to access OAuth token." in Job additional option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it has been replaced, but you need to see this change in the output repos.

For more clearly, you could use **private agent** to run this build. Then go the corresponding local repos and check the `Var.json` file after the build finished:

[image]

In your script, you are `Set-Content` into the file which exists under the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Var.json`, not the one which stored in `VSTS repos`. So, to check whether it is replaced successfully, please go your `output repos`, the one in agent.

Sometimes, if what you used is hosted agent, you may could not view the detailed output repos since the host image will be recycled by the server after the pipeline finished.

At this time, you can add another script in it to print the JSON file content out, then you could check whether it is replaced successfully:

```
$content= Get-Content -Path $JsonPath
Write-Host $content
```

[image]

---

In addition, please make a little change into your script:

```
$JsonBase.FileNames[0].value = "$(FileRes)"
```

Here please use `$(FileRes)` instead of `$FileRes`, since you specified the value in the **Variables** tab. And do not forget the double quote `""`.

**Update:**

To sync the output repos change back into VSTS repos, try follow:

[image]

(1) The first command line task:

```
git config --global user.email "xxx@xx.com"
git config --global user.name "Merlin"

cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
git init
```

(2) In powershell task, execute `set-content` script.

(3) In second command line task, do `git push` to push the changes:

```
git add Var.json
git commit -m "aaaa"
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxxx
git push -u origin HEAD:master
```

[image]

In addition, to run git script successfully in pipeline. Beside enable “Allow script to access........” you also should follow this [permission setting.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#enable-scripts-to-run-git-commands)

Comment: In order to push json file changes to devops Repo I decided to add separate task in my pipeline, powershell task. in Inline script section I ve pasted presented code: git config --global user.email "xxx@no-mail.com"
git config --global user.name "xxx"
git add var.json
git commit -m "Json file update"
git push. I used option: "Allow scripts to access OAuth token.", but facing errors due. This git code block is correct or should I add something?

Comment: @tester81 Looks very make sense. Is it completely succeed?

Comment: still is something wrong, this time with this git code block

Comment: @tester81 There’re something missing in your script block. Have update my answer with this, please check my updated answer.

Comment: I added all required permissions, used link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml. I have created CMD tasks as You suggested, 1 and 2nd task completed succesfully, but 3rd ended with the issue --> "fatal: could not read Username for 'https://dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled". My first task contains lines:  git config --global user.email "agent@no-mail.com"
git config --global user.name "Robot Agent"
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
git init

Comment: I corrected the link in this line--> "git remote add origin https://xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxxx", and finally it worked, @Merlin thank You vary much!!! great support!

Comment: @tester81. Awesome! You are so welcome:-) My pleasure could give you this assistance.