# How to edit the csv file while runs the Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have a requirement where I need to edit and set some values in the CSV files.

basically, I will set some variable values when starting the build pipeline.
eg. Test1

CSV file looks like

```
ProjectName      IsTestCaseRun
Test1             False
Test2             False
Test3             False
```

So Test1 will be my variable value, and I'll need to alter the

```
Test1 Project IsTestCaseRun to TRUE.
```

Please let me know if is there any way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Basic question: _where_ is this CSV file? in a repo? and is this something you can just manage through pipeline variables? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: Yes it will be in the git hub repo only

Comment: Then I guess you need to check it out, change it, check it in, _or_ change it after it is cloned for the build process. Again, see if you can solve this with pipeline variables if possible

Comment: my question is how to change the value in CSV file?? If I am able to do the changes in files then I have script which can perform the automatic check in during running build pipeline

Comment: I would write a powershell script to do it in and just use standard pwershell to edit a file.  But how do you determine what the values to be are?

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873938/azure-devops-update-json-file-powershell-script

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid:- Simply I just want to change the False to True based on the Project Name doesn't matter what is the previous value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234433/discussion-between-sudhir-goswami-and-nick-mcdermaid).